# How to transfer a Class to another Class in Objective-C？

Tags: ios, model, objective-c-blocks

ForExample ，I Have a Class named PlayListModel, which have a properties：id . and I have other Classes like PlayModel_A or PlayModel_B ,which have many properties。

Now what I want is there have a method like:

```
  - (PlayListModel*)transferAnClass:(id)anClass ToPlayListModel;
```

I want transfer other model to the uniform PlayListModel , than pass the PlayListModel to the player.

My problem is , the other model's source name is different. some is 'idField' and some is 'idsource' or something other . so the need to transfer them to the Playlist's property name :'id'(for example).

i tried to use run time , but i can't get the definitely name of class, they could be any modelClasses.

I can use [class Class] to know which class it is . but then I can't use Class.property . I don't know how to explain .

Comment: Why isn't `Student` a type of `Person`?

Comment: What you have mentioned is classic case of inheritance. Your Student and Police must inherit from People class. Then you will automatically have those two properties.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you want to do is subclass People..

```
@interface Student : People
//properties & method names here
@end

@implementation Student
//code here
@end
```

Comment: the problem is not so easy. I can't use inheritance. because some model may have same properties. and others don't . I have edit my question.

Comment: why do same models have different property names?  Sorry, I'm not understanding

Answer (score -1):

You can create a model of People separately and use object of that model in Student or Police

```
class People   { 
    private var _age : Int = 0
    private var _name : String = ""
}
```

and Student class as

```
class Student   { 
private var _student_id : Int = 0
private var _student_rollno : String = ""
let _people : People 
}
```

if you need to send data you can directly pass object of Student or Police class.

You can also opt for inheritance.Inherit your People class in Student or Police class. You can access and modify properties of People class in Student or Police class easily.

Comment: if you want it in Objective-C do let me know.

Comment: Y downvote?? One should always specify reason for the same. I missed language tag thatsy in swift. If required I can provide same in Objective-C

Comment: it's not me. the problem is not so easy. I have edite my question.